# Java - empty orc file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, orc

I am trying to write orc files using [orc-core](https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html) to be later read by hive.

The files being written have the correct number of rows, but **there's no content in the columns**. I can see that both trying to read the file with a select query in hive, and both with `hive --orcfiledump -d`.

I tried the example provided in the guide, which writes two **long type** columns, and the file produced is correctly read by hive. I suspect this has to do with the fact that I am writing instead **string columns**, but I still cannot make it work.

That's how I am currently writing the file:

```
    //  File schema
    String outputFormat = "struct<";
    for(int i=0;i<outputSchema.length;i++){
        outputFormat+=outputSchema[i]+":string,";
    }
    outputFormat+="lastRecordHash:string,currentHash:string>";
    TypeDescription orcSchema = TypeDescription.fromString(outputFormat);

    //  Initializes buffers
    VectorizedRowBatch batch = orcSchema.createRowBatch();
    ArrayList<BytesColumnVector> orcBuffers = new ArrayList<>(numFields+2);
    for(int i=0;i<numFields+2;i++){
        BytesColumnVector bcv = (BytesColumnVector) batch.cols[i];
        orcBuffers.add(i, bcv);
    }

    ...

    //  Initializes writer
    Writer writer=null;
    try{
        writer = OrcFile.createWriter(new Path(hdfsUri+outputPath), OrcFile.writerOptions(conf).setSchema(orcSchema));
        partitionCounter++;
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        log.error("Cannot open hdfs file. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
        session.transfer(flowfile, hdfsFailure);
        return;
    }

    //  Writes content
    String[] records = ...

    for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
        fields = records[i].split(fieldSeparator);

        int row=batch.size++;

        //  Filling the orc buffers
        for(int j=0;j<numFields;j++){
            orcBuffers.get(j).vector[row] = fields[j].getBytes();
            hashDigest.append(fields[j]);
        }
        if (batch.size == batch.getMaxSize()) {
            try{
                writer.addRowBatch(batch);
                batch.reset();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                log.error("Cannot write to hdfs. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }         
    }
    if (batch.size != 0) {
        try{
            writer.addRowBatch(batch);
            batch.reset();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            log.error("Cannot write to hdfs. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
    writer.close();
```

Any suggestion or helpful reference is really appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an-in depth review of the API doc was what I needed. What I was missing:

- Call `initBuffer()` on each `BytesColumnVector` in the initialization phase
- Assign the value of the columns calling `setVal()`. This can be accomplished using also `setRef()`. It is documented to be the fastest of the two, but I don't know if fits my specific case, I will try it.

This is the updated code:

```
//  File schema
String outputFormat = "struct<";
for(int i=0;i<outputSchema.length;i++){
    outputFormat+=outputSchema[i]+":string,";
}
outputFormat+="lastRecordHash:string,currentHash:string>";
TypeDescription orcSchema = TypeDescription.fromString(outputFormat);

//  Initializes buffers
VectorizedRowBatch batch = orcSchema.createRowBatch();
ArrayList<BytesColumnVector> orcBuffers = new ArrayList<>(numFields+2);
for(int i=0;i<numFields+2;i++){
    BytesColumnVector bcv = (BytesColumnVector) batch.cols[i];
    bcv.initBuffer();
    orcBuffers.add(i, bcv);
}

...

//  Initializes writer
Writer writer=null;
try{
    writer = OrcFile.createWriter(new Path(hdfsUri+outputPath), OrcFile.writerOptions(conf).setSchema(orcSchema));
    partitionCounter++;
}
catch(IOException e){
    log.error("Cannot open hdfs file. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
    session.transfer(flowfile, hdfsFailure);
    return;
}

//  Writes content
String[] records = ...

for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
    fields = records[i].split(fieldSeparator);

    int row=batch.size++;

    //  Filling the orc buffers
    for(int j=0;j<numFields;j++){
        orcBuffers.get(j).setVal(row, fields[j].getBytes());
        hashDigest.append(fields[j]);
    }
    if (batch.size == batch.getMaxSize()) {
        try{
            writer.addRowBatch(batch);
            batch.reset();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            log.error("Cannot write to hdfs. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }         
}
if (batch.size != 0) {
    try{
        writer.addRowBatch(batch);
        batch.reset();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        log.error("Cannot write to hdfs. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
writer.close();
```